# Angular2 composure

Tags: proxy, angular, composition

I'm looking into microservices and to be more exact Angular2 microservices. The main idea seems easy enough but it gets complicated as I want to make a composure of different Angular2 apps.

What I mean by this, imagine I have 2 apps which I don't have a lot of control over, app A and app B, created by different teams, each one serving a different thing (one might be a 2D viewer, the other a 3D viewer). I was thinking of building some kind of composition proxy in which I define a html file with some custom tags such as `<service target = "url">` and then have the proxy make a composition and serve it to the user.

I've been researching the web for a while now and I can't seem to find anything on angular2 compositions. Here are a few of the problems I encountered :

- The order of the included scripts. Since each app might require different scripts to be included, not including them in the right order might crash the entire app.
- Building a totally new "core" component that is properly bootstrapped, having only the right components being bootstrapped and all that.
- Making sure css from one app doesn't overwrite css from the other
- Naming issues, since apps are different I might encounter components with the same name.

All those issues seem fixable to me by just parsing every file and modifying it accordingly. Problem is the same idea won't exactly work if the js files are both minified and unified. Also it would take a lot of processing power to do this for every request (I'd like it to be a bit hot-builded/loaded).

What are some ways I should go about building such a composition proxy and is there any examples/documentation on how to do this?

Comment: An app is not a service. What exactly would be the point of combining a viewer and a game? A viewer game? I rather think you want to use functionality from one in the other. Then we are back at square one: An app is not a service.

Comment: @zeroflagL I'm looking for a way to combine totally different components, coming from different servers, each of which being independently deployable. Maybe calling them microservices was not a wise choice of words and that example is a bit extreme. A better example would be a 2D viewer on the left side and a 3D one on the right one each being developed by a different team.

Comment: It seems like the simplest thing to do would be to use iframes.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand what you want to do but I can see from your requirement all you need is out of the box Angular2 functionality.

> 1) The order of the included scripts. Since each app might require
>   different scripts to be included, not including them in the right
>   order might crash the entire app.
>
> 2) Building a totally new "core"
>   component that is properly bootstrapped, having only the right
>   components being bootstrapped and all that.
>
> 3) Making sure css from one
>   app doesn't overwrite css from the other Naming issues, since apps are
>   different I might encounter components with the same name

I'll answer to your points:

1) You just use **dynamic module loading** in you "app-routing", like the following:

```
export function loadModuleA() {
    return System.import('./pages/module-A-view/a.module').then(mod => mod.ModuleA)
}

export function loadModuleB() {
    return System.import('./pages/module-B-view/a.module').then(mod => mod.ModuleA)
}

export const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'core/sectionA',
        loadChildren: loadModuleA
    },
     {
        path: 'core/sectionB',
        loadChildren: loadModuleB
    },
```

If you `import` a library in **ModuleA** is not going to be available in **ModuleB** unless you explicitly `export` it each module A and module B will have their own dependencies

2) you specify your "core" as you main `app.module.ts`and module dependencies in their own module file, simple.

3) you only need a main stylesheet really, then every component can have their custom files. If you use **angular cli**, for example every time you create a new component, the cli will generate the component file, the scss file, the html file and the spec file. Otherwise you can just as easily do it yourself:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'whatever',
    templateUrl: './whatever.component.html',
    styleUrls: [ './whatever.component.scss' ]  
})
export class WhateverComponent
```

If you instead wanted a StyleSheet specific to all components of (let's say) Module A, then I don't know how to do that.